# Removing rows that are similar in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My data looks something like this:

```
    Source   Target    Value
1  Charlie     Mac 0.6530945
2   Dennis    Fank 0.7296234
3  Charlie   Frank 0.4750875
4      Mac  Dennis 0.3961787
5  Charlie  Dennis 0.6213751
6      Mac   Frank 0.9727454
7    Frank Charlie 0.4750875
8      Mac Charlie 0.6530945
9    Frank     Mac 0.9727454
10   Frank  Dennis 0.7296234
11  Dennis     Mac 0.3961787
12  Dennis Charlie 0.6213751
```

I have 2 columns with names and the third gives a relationship value. So row 1 is basically the same as row 8 and row 2 is the same as row 10 etc. So the order of names in (source, target) does not matter. What I want to do is get rid of these unneeded rows to get something like this:

```
    Source  Target     Value
1  Charlie     Mac 0.6530945
2   Dennis    Fank 0.7296234
3  Charlie   Frank 0.4750875
4      Mac  Dennis 0.3961787
5  Charlie  Dennis 0.6213751
6      Mac   Frank 0.9727454
```

Obviously in this simple example I could just return the first six rows but my dataset is too large for that. I can't just return only unique items in the "Value" column because some unrelated rows might have the same values.

Comment: Do you have some code that you have attempted to complete the problem with?

Comment: Is `Fank` a typo?

Answer (score 5):

```
df[~pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[['Source', 'Target']], 1), df.index).duplicated()]

    Source  Target     Value
1  Charlie     Mac  0.653095
2   Dennis   Frank  0.729623
3  Charlie   Frank  0.475087
4      Mac  Dennis  0.396179
5  Charlie  Dennis  0.621375
6      Mac   Frank  0.972745
```

Comment: I was at `df[~df[['Source', 'Target']].apply(np.sort, axis=1).duplicated(keep='first')]`

Comment: @piRSquared a similar approach was used in your previous question right

Comment: @Bharathshetty Correct